# Setting up OpenCV. g++ error missing argument to ‘-l’. Linking error

Tags: c++, opencv, g++, pkg-config

I'm trying to setup a trivial OpenCV example following instructions from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV). But when I try to run my example using

```
$ g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename opencvtest.cpp .cpp` opencvtest.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
$ ./opencvtest`
```

I get the following error
`g++ error missing argument to ‘-l’`

I would appreciate any insight on how I could solve this.

Comment: Do `echo g++ -ggdb \`pkg-config --cflags opencv\` -o \`basename opencvtest.cpp .cpp\` opencvtest.cpp \`pkg-config --libs opencv\`` to see the real command you are executing.